# Session data lost so fast and rapidly in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have build a web application using codeignitet. It's about 200 users in my application. When user login, it success, but the session data just keep about one minutes and then kills automatically.

I use ci_sessions to store custom session data.

This is my session configuration :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 900;
```

In my application, if session kill it redirect to login page. It always redirect and redirect to login page, i think it cause the session data lost rapidly. Need Helps and Thanks.

Comment: I need your code to tell what's wrong. Your config seems to be alright, if the sessions table exists.

Comment: When login success, i get user role data from database and save it in session. There 4 role in my application, my bad code is, I always use session role data to validate user authorize in my web.

Comment: When login success, i get user role data from database and save it in session. There 4 role in my application, my bad code is, I always use session role data to validate user authorize in my web.

Comment: @Stephan S. : Is it good or not always use session data to check user authorize in each page in my web. Thanks.

Comment: Its impossible to help you if you do not post some sort of code sir. -1.

Comment: sample of my code (http://pastebin.com/pHL2YVjd). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your session's configuration looks Okay and you're also storing it in a database which is a good practice too.

It seems like is some place in your code you're destroying the session or part of it.
We have to see some code if you're unable to trace it yourself.

Good Luck!

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with the session handling in this piece of code. Check the other part of your code or your server.

Comment: Is it good or not to use session data to validate user authorize in each page in my web ? thanks.

Comment: Once you validate the user, there is no need to validate again on every page, however, it's good to re-validate before a transaction is being made or other important actions

Comment: I mean, validate the iformation that should perform in webpage. Such as, if role administrator show information A, in the other, if role general user show information B. Thanks.